# Adding zeros to a float in a list so that all elements have the same number of digits

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a Dataframe and I need to have all elements in a column having the same number of digits. For example, I have a list [9.0 , 100.0, ... , 5910.0, 85455.0] and I would like to get a formated list like [9.00000, 100.000, ... , 5910.00, 85455.0]. How can I do that please ?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can format the column named `c` to strings of (for example) 6 digits of precision using:

```
df[c] = df[c].map("{:#.6g}".format)
```

If you do not wish to change the original DataFrame, and only print it as such, you can print it using a formatter just for that column:

```
df.to_string(formatters={c: "{:#.6g}".format})
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. However, I've already tried this and this leads to have all my elements having 6 zeros after. What I want is to have all my elements having the same number of digits, i.e if I have for example 85000.0 which is the biggest element, I want the others elements to have the same length by adding zero after the float. In fact, I don't want to add zero to all elements, just those which have a shorter length.

Comment: @sacha Try the updated answer. Formatting with `#.6g` does what you want I think (as opposed to `.6f`).